# A list inside a table

Tags: tables, lists, itemize, resume

I'm using this simple code to align date ranges on a CV:

```
\section{I'm pretty cool}\begin{tabular}{l l}
2009--present & company 1 \\
2011--2012 & company 2
\end{tabular}
```

Now this looks like this:

```
2009 - present   company 1
2011 - 2012      company 2
```

but I'd like to add a list in each of the entries, like this:

```
2009 - present   company 1:
                   * editor
2011 - 2012      company 2
                   * judge
                   * jury 
                   * executioner
```

How can I achieve this? I could `itemize` them in a separate column, but it doesn't work inside `tabular` in cases like this, where I want part of "company 2" to be in that column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use `itemize` inside a `p` column in `tabular` a lot of unnecessary space is added. Use a properly defined column type to do the right thing. The following was posted on CTT a long time ago by Donald Arseneau for itemized and enumerated cells.

*Edit:* Change `\multicolumn` contents to a `p` column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{e}[1]{%--- Enumerated cells ---
   >{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
     \NoHyper%                Hyperref adds a vertical space
     \let\\\tabularnewline
     \enumerate
        \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 50pt}% for raggedright
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}%
   p{#1}%
   <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\endenumerate
     \endNoHyper
     \endminipage}}

\newcolumntype{i}[1]{%--- Itemized cells ---
   >{\minipage[t]{\linewidth}%
        \let\\\tabularnewline
        \itemize
           \addtolength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 50pt}%
           \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}}%
   p{#1}%
   <{\@finalstrut\@arstrutbox\enditemize\endminipage}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{}%
        {\let\NoHyper\relax\let\endNoHyper\relax}}
\makeatother

\newlength{\pcolwdth}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\pcolwdth}{5cm}% 
\begin{tabular}{li{\pcolwdth}}
2009--present & \multicolumn{1}{p{\pcolwdth}}{company 1} \\
              & \item editor                             \\
2011--2012    & \multicolumn{1}{p{\pcolwdth}}{company 2} \\
              & \item judge
                \item jury
                \item executioner                        \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your preference, you might just as well avoid lists and set the items using a "fake list" environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\nextitem}{\par\hspace*{\labelsep}\textbullet\hspace*{\labelsep}}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{rp{3in}}
  2009--present & company 1
    \nextitem editor \\
  2011--2012 & company 2
    \nextitem jury
    \nextitem executioner
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This only works because the second column is set in `p`aragraph mode. You could also use an `X`-column (from the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)).

An alternative suggestion altogether would be to use the [`moderncv` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). Here's an extract from the [`moderncv` template/example](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template.pdf) (there are other [examples](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples)):

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but if the item is more than a line long, it does not line up the text (I believe I had the (final) answer to one of my [previous questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58180/numbered-hanging-paragraph-without-list-environment).

Answer (score 5):

The list environment does not work inside `l` columns, but it is fine inside `p` columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tabular}{l<{\raggedright}p{3in}}
  2009--present & company 1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item editor
  \end{itemize}
  \\
  2011--2012 & company 2
  \begin{itemize}
  \item jury
  \item executioner
  \end{itemize}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Not exactly using `tabular`. But this solution uses `parallel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parallel,enumitem}
\setlist{label=*,leftmargin=0.31\textwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[v]{0.24\textwidth}{0.74\textwidth} % remove [v] if you don't need a vertical line
\ParallelLText{\noindent
2009--present
}
%
\ParallelRText{%
\noindent
Company 1
\begin{enumerate}%[label=*,leftmargin=0.31\textwidth] %defined by \setlist in preamble
  \item{editor}
\end{enumerate}}
\ParallelPar
\bigskip
%---------------------
\ParallelLText{\noindent
2011--2012
}
%
\ParallelRText{%
\noindent
Company 1
\begin{enumerate}%[label=*,leftmargin=0.31\textwidth]
  \item{Judge}
  \item{Jury}
  \item{Executioner}
\end{enumerate}}
\ParallelPar
\bigskip
%---------------------
\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]