# Numbered, hanging paragraph without list environment

Tags: lists, numbering, indentation, paragraphs, quoting

I often quote text (legal sources). Normally I use the `quoting`-package and `csquotes` (`block quote`).

Often, the quotation contains some lists, and often with a non-standard numbering (f. ex. § 4-1(a)), or I have to start the numbering at a arbitrary level. I find it cumbersome to define `newlist` environments using `enumitem` because all I need is one or two paragraph of text. Inside a quoting environment, I often struggle to define the correct indentation with `enumitem`.

What is the easiest and best solution? If the solution survives nested quoting-environment, it is a bonus (for me).

```
This is the quoted text that suddenly
and unfortunately contains some numbered
paragraphs:
11. Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum. 
[...]
17. Lorem ipsum sucendium ipsum Lorem ipsum 
    Lorem ipsum.
```

To make my question clearer (maybe): What I am looking for, was a command (f ex `\hi` for hanging indent) to put in between the number and rest of the text, aligning the remaining text f. ex. at `parindent` from the last used left margin.

```
11.\hi Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
    Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.
```

That is: Something similar to put a TAB between a character and rest of the text in a paragraph in M$ Word, and then press CTRL+T.

Comment: Please provide a MWE where `enumitem` plus `quoting` results in incorrect list indentation.

Comment: I said _I_ struggled to find the correct indentation. Not that the packages produced _incorrect_ indentation. If you need may be four or five different lists due to inconsistent numbering schemes in your source, defining `mylists` with `enumitem` is not the simplest, in my opinion.

Comment: The non-standard numbering isn't too worrying- you can always use the `enumitem` package to `resume` lists. If it comes to it, you can always provide the `\item` with its optional argument, e.g, `\item[17]` (although that's obviously not ideal)

Comment: I know I can use `enumitem` and tweak it to whatever I want. My wish was that somebody would show me a simpler solution to make a hanging paragraph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a need to define new `enumerate`-like environments with `\newlist` when combining `enumitem` and `quoting`. Simply use keys like `label*` and `start` in the optional argument of specific `enumerate` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{quoting}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\sometext
%
\begin{quoting}
\sometext

\begin{enumerate}[label*=\Roman*]
\item An item with Roman numering
\end{enumerate}
%
\sometext

\begin{enumerate}[start=21]
\item An abitrarily numbered item
\end{enumerate}
\end{quoting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found a solution in "Tex by Topic", but it did not function inside the "quote"-environment. What I need is a macro that scans until first space, put the scanned characters in a hbox, measure the box, advance the leftmargin to `parindent-box` and line up rest of the paragraph at `parindent`. And can be used in a `list/trivlist`-environment. I found some code in the `footmisc`-package that may be adaptable (except is have no scanning).