# Itemize inside longtable

Tags: tables, lists, longtable, itemize

I have the following (Non-working) example.

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{longtable}{lcl}
    \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}\\ \toprule
    \label{tab:FallPredictionVariables}
    \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \textbf{Determinants}\\
    \midrule

    \noindent Author 1 &
    1780 (?) & 
    \begin{itemize}%[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Recent falls (last 2 months)
        \item Agitation
        \item Frequent toileting
        \item Visual impairment
    \end{itemize}\\

    \noindent Author 2 &
    311 (?) &
    \begin{itemize}%[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Posture sway
        \item Two or more falls in previous year
        \item Low hand grip strength
        \item Depressive state of mind
    \end{itemize}\\
        \bottomrule

\end{longtable}
```

However, it works OK outside a `longtable` environment:

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling} 
    \label{tab:FallPredictionVariables}
    \begin{tabular}{lcp{60mm}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \textbf{Determinants}\\
    \midrule

    \noindent Author 1 &
    1780 (?) & 
    \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Recent falls (last 2 months)
        \item Agitation
        \item Frequent toileting
        \item Visual impairment
    \end{itemize}\\

    \noindent Author 2 &
    311 (?) &
    \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Posture sway
        \item Two or more falls in previous year
        \item Low hand grip strength
        \item Depressive state of mind
    \end{itemize}\\
        \bottomrule

        \end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

As you can see in the picture below, it does what I'm expecting (except there is some vertical space over the first item that I would like to remove, and the solutions posted in [How to reduce vertical space itemize environment inside table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114280/how-to-reduce-vertical-space-itemize-environment-inside-table) only seem to work for `tabularx` environments).

[image]

I'm unable to make my code work inside `longtable`, and I really need it (the complete table is very long).

Any ideas for both things:

1. To be able to have itemize inside `longtable` environment
2. Eliminate the extra space for the first item

PS: This is the preamble for both examples:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}  
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: code snippets a good, but MWE are better :)

Comment: @cmhughes I'm really having a hard time telling the difference when to post the complete MWE or just the code snippet for the sake of space... I don't know if what I just did is the best approach

Comment: related: [A list inside a table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54039)

Comment: @MarioS.E.: Most of us can't debug code by eyes alone.  We have to copy and paste into a document, see what happens, poke it, see what happens, curse it, see what happens, etc. ... With an MWE we can get more quickly to the poking-and-cursing stage.  Without it we have to manually type repetitive things like `\documentclass...\begin{document}...` and so on. Also we have to guess what packages are being loaded (especially annoying with multi-library packages like `tikz` and `pgfplots`), and it's a barrier to actually solving the problem.  So MWE is *always* good if you want easy help. :-)

Comment: To the question: couldn't multiple rows work just as easily?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes, that is a valid approach

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Could you please write an answer with an example?  I'm really intrigued if this could work for a `longtable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a full MWE, I've taken some code from [Przemysław Scherwentke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114828/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\usepackage{array,booktabs,enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{array,booktabs,enumitem}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\endgraf\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}p{4cm}P{6cm}}
  \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}\label{tab:FallPredictionVariables} \\
  \toprule
  \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Determinants}} \\
  \midrule

  \noindent Author 1 &
  1780 (?) & 
  \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
    \item Recent falls (last 2 months)
    \item Agitation
    \item Frequent toileting
    \item Visual impairment
  \end{itemize}\\

  \noindent Author 2 &
  311 (?) & 
  \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
    \item Posture sway
    \item Two or more falls in previous year
    \item Low hand grip strength
    \item Depressive state of mind
  \end{itemize}\\
  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The `P{<len>}` column type (thanks to [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)) inserts a "vertical unskip" so that the first item aligns properly with the remainder of the table.

The assumption is that the last `P`-column only contains lists, of course. If not, a separate `\multicolumn` has to be issued like with the heading **Determinants**.

Comment: Will it break properly at the end of a page?

Comment: @Werner This `\newcolumntype` is a beautiful solution to obtain globally that I had changed locally. To remember!

Comment: @Werner this is indeed a good practical solution to the problem at hand, but what are your thoughts about the original question? Is is possible to have an `itemize` inside a `longtable` environment?

Comment: @MarioS.E.: As you can see I'm using `itemize` inside a `longtable`. It will break properly across rows, but not within a row (if you have a long `itemize`, say).

Comment: @Werner thanks! that's the confirmation I was hoping :)

Comment: For information on the difference between `topsep` and `partopsep`, check out this related question: [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep, \parsep - what do they each mean \(and what about the bottom\)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/).

Answer (score 7):

The following is a working example. Because `lcr` are for one-line entries, `itemize` shouldn't work with them. Compare the first part, improved, with the second, unchanged.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,11pt,openright]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}  
%\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}   
\usepackage{enumitem}   
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
%\begin{longtable}{lcl}
\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}p{4cm}p{6cm}}
    \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}\\ \toprule
    \label{tab:FallPredictionVariables}
    \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \textbf{Determinants}\\
    \midrule

    \noindent Author 1 &
    1780 (?) & \vspace{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Recent falls (last 2 months)
        \item Agitation
        \item Frequent toileting
        \item Visual impairment
    \end{itemize}\\

    \noindent Author 2 &
    311 (?) &
    \begin{itemize}%[label={--},noitemsep,leftmargin=*,topsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item Posture sway
        \item Two or more falls in previous year
        \item Low hand grip strength
        \item Depressive state of mind
    \end{itemize}\\
        \bottomrule

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for the "\vspace{-\baselineskip}" part, that seems to solve a similar issue I had.

Answer (score 4):

I thought you could achieve this effect without having to hack an `itemize`.  Just use multiple rows of the table:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{longtable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{4cm}p{4cm}>{-- }p{6cm}}
  \caption{Summary of proven determinants for falling}\label{tab:FallPredictionVariables} \\
  \toprule
  \textbf{Author} &\textbf{Subject count (M:F)} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Determinants}} \\
  \midrule

  \noindent 
  Author 1 & 1780 (?) & Recent falls (last 2 months) \\
           &          & Agitation                    \\
           &          & Frequent toileting           \\ 
           &          & Visual impairment            \\[1.8\baselineskip]

  Author 2 & 311 (?)  & Posture sway                 \\
           &          & Two or more falls in previous year \\
           &          & Low hand grip strength \\
           &          & Depressive state of mind \\               
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample code output]

Comment: Saving keystrokes must be upvoted. :-)

Comment: This is a really good solution as well