# How to add `parsep` to `itemsep` and set `parsep` to 0pt, when declaring my list?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

By reading [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-and-parsep-what-does-each-of-them-mean-and-wha), I learned how spacing works, therefore I am trying to do some spacing settings/adjusting.

Initially I tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\parsep+\itemsep,parsep=0pt] % <--- Here

        \item https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp

            Some text.

        \item https://github.com/trishume/syntect

    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But the the compiler seems not liked:

```
test.tex:12: Missing number, treated as zero. [...rate}[itemsep=\parsep+\itemsep,parsep=0pt]]
test.tex:12: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). [...rate}[itemsep=\parsep+\itemsep,parsep=0pt]]
```

---

## Update

I would like to:

1. Sum the `parsep` and `itemsep` values
2. Attribute them to my list option `itemsep`
3. And set `parsep` to zero.

This is a picture about it from [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-and-parsep-what-does-each-of-them-mean-and-wha):

[image]

Comment: `\dimexpr\parsep+\itemsep\relax`

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve here. If you want to add lengths you need to add `\usepackage{calc}` but what do you think `itemsep=\itemsep+\parsep` should give you?

Comment: I want to sum the `parsep` and `itemsep` values, attribute them to my list `itemsep`and set `parsep` to zero. I Updated the question within a picture. Thanks @DavidCarlisle, I tried your expression and it worked!

Comment: Ok. If you don't feel like dealing with the raw TeX that @DavidCarlisle suggested you can simply load the `calc` package instead (a bit more LaTeXy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems a slightly strange setting for the list but the arithmetic can be performed using an e-tex dimension expression.

```
\dimexpr\parsep+\itemsep\relax
```

Answer (score 3):

A more LaTeXy way to do this is to load the `calc` package, and then you don't need the `\dimexpr` and `\relax` in David's answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=\parsep+\itemsep,parsep=0pt] 

    \item https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp

        Some text.

    \item https://github.com/trishume/syntect

\end{document}
```