# What do we call the vertical space between a list item label and the item text?

Tags: spacing, lists, description, terminology

Following the diagram here:

[\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean (and what about the bottom)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300340/5640)

is there a name for the *vertical* rather than horizontal space between the label of an item in a list and its corresponding text (for the case where the label is longer than `\leftmargin` so the text gets pushed down)?

I'm not finding any such term in the [documentation of enumitem](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: This happens  with some description styles. The usual \baselineskip is used, so it doesn't need to have a name.

Comment: I’m not sure to understand what you are asking for, but try adding `\leavevmode\\*[\smallskipamount]` (say) just after the closing bracket of the relevant `\item[...]` command.

Comment: @Bernard: So you're telling me there's no way to control it independently of \baselineskip? :-(

Comment: @JohnKormylo: I'm reading your comments, but I must be missing something since they sound like an answer to another question :-(

Comment: @GuM: That seems to always insert at least one empty paragraph, even if I replace `\smallskipamount` with, say, `1pt`. Can't I avoid that somehow?

Comment: @Bernard: Also, if you're sure - please make that an answer.

Comment: @einpoklum: Your reply makes me think that I’m indeed misunderstanding your goal.  Could you please clarify your question, and add a Minimal (possibly-non-)Working Example?

Comment: @einpoklum: I've updated my answer to give an example on how to control the vertical spacing for `description` environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, there is no vertical spacing between the label of an item in one of the standard  lists and the following text – only a horizontal spacing, namely `\labelsep` and `\itemindent`.

However, as mentioned by @GuM, you can manage to have a line break manually, and it's up to you to add such a spacing. This is easy for `enumerate` and `itemize`, writing `\leavevmode\\[some verticalskip]` just after `\item`.

Unfortunately it doesn't work for `description` environments. I propose a solution, which consists in defining a new `Description` environment for which the `\descriptionlabel` command is redefined to incorporate an invisible rule below the base line. The length of this rule is an optional argument of the environment (rather arbitrary default: 3mm). Thanks to `xparse`, the environment accepts a second optional argument, for the set of `key = some value` to be handed to the `description` environment.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[description]{leftmargin = 12mm}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Description}{O{3mm}O{}}{\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\rule[-#1]{0pt}{#1}\hspace\labelsep
                            \normalfont\bfseries ##1}\description[style =standard, labelwidth=\textwidth, #2]}{\enddescription}

\begin{document}

‘Force next line’:

\begin{Description}[1.8ex][font=\sffamily\color{FireBrick!60}]
\item[One]\lipsum[4]
\item[And another one] \lipsum[4]
\end{Description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My crystal ball suggests that you might be using the `style=nextline` key that the `enumitem` package provides for `description` environment.  If this is the case, the workaround I suggested in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384939/vertical-space-between-list-item-label-and-the-item-text#comment953397_384939) is *obviously* not applicable.  However, since the `nextitem` style doesn’t “box” the label, you can achieve what you want by including an appropriate `\vspace` command at the *end* of your label text, as the following MWE shows:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{enumitem}



\begin{document}

Preceding text.

\begin{description}[style=nextline,leftmargin=6pc]

    \item[A]
        The text of the first description.

    \item[Short label]
        Full description of the second item in the list follows here.
        Let's add a few words so that it makes it to the second line.

    \item[A somewhat longer label]
        Here's the text of the thirs description, or, better, the description of
        the third item in the list.

    \item[Similar, but with vertical space\vspace{\smallskipamount}]
        Replace the argument of \verb|\vspace| (here, \verb|\smallskipamount|) 
        with any rubber length of your choice.

    \item[Abc def ghij\vspace{\smallskipamount}]
        If the label is ``short'', then it gets boxed, thus suppressing the 
        vertical spacing.

    \item[Wrong]\leavevmode\\*[\smallskipamount]
        The workaround I~suggested in a comment does \emph{not} work as 
        expexted in the context of a \texttt{description} environment with 
        \texttt{style=nextline}, neither for ``short'' labels\ldots

    \item[And wrong as well]\leavevmode\\*[\smallskipamount]
        \ldots nor for ``long'' ones; retrospectively, this is obvious!

\end{description}

Following text.

\end{document}
```

Here’s the output I get:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Your crystal ball reads true. I'll try to make my issue into a separate question to which you could move this answer, but generating a MWE is proving a bit tricky.