# How to treat lists like regular text (regarding vertical spacing)?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumitem

**Context:**  I want to treat lists (itemize, enumerate, and description) just like regular text for what regards vertical spacing. Namely:

> 1. If the list starts a paragraph, insert a vertical `\parskip` beforehand — no vertical spacing otherwise;
> 2. No vertical spacing between items of the list;
> 3. If the list ends a paragraph, insert a vertical `\parskip` afterwards — no vertical spacing otherwise.

I have notably used information found in [\topsep, \itemsep, \partopsep and \parsep - what does each of them mean](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300340/64454).

Requirement #1 is solved with `\setlist{topsep=-\parskip,partopsep=\parskip}`.

Requirement #2 is solved with `\setlist{noitemsep}`.

**Problem:** 
There remain two issues with Requirement #3:

- A vertical space is added *after* the list if the latter starts a paragraph, even if this list is *immediately* followed by text. (I.e. there is no such thing as an idependent `parbottomsep` length).
- If a *new* paragraph starts after the list, this paragraph *is not* preceded with a `\parskip`.

**Question:**
How to comply with Requirement #3?
(I currently use manual patches — see MWE below — but it is of course not satisfactory.)

[image]

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist{%
        topsep=-\parskip,
        partopsep=\parskip,
        noitemsep,
    }
\begin{document}
    This sentence is a paragraph on its own; there is thus a vertical parskip prior next paragraph.

    Following list is \emph{within} a paragraph, with preceding and appended text.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One,
        \item Two,
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Two and a half;
            \item Almost three.
        \end{itemize}
        \item Three.
    \end{itemize}
    This text is appended to the previous list.
    However, following list starts a new paragraph on its own.

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Did you notice the vertical spacing preceding this list?
        \item Two,
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Two and a half;
            \item Almost three.
        \end{enumerate}
        \item Three.
    \end{enumerate}
%   \vspace{-\parskip}                                  %quick and dirty solution
    \textbf{There shouldn't be a vertical spacing here.}
    This text is appended to the previous list too.

    And finally, a list with preceding text only.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item One,
        \item Two,
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Two and a half;
            \item Almost three.
        \end{itemize}
        \item Three.
    \end{itemize}

%   \null\par                                            %quick and dirty solution
    \textbf{There should be a vertical spacing here.}
    This is a new paragraph.
    It should thus be preceded with parskip.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is hardly less dirty, but it uses the tools provided by `enumitem`, playing with the `after` key:

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{%
    topsep=-\parskip,
    partopsep=\parskip,
    noitemsep,
}

\begin{document}

This sentence is a paragraph on its own; there is thus a vertical parskip prior next paragraph.

Following list is \emph{within} a paragraph, with preceding and appended text.
\begin{itemize}
    \item One,
    \item Two,
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Two and a half;
        \item Almost three.
    \end{itemize}
    \item Three.
\end{itemize}
This text is appended to the previous list.
However, following list starts a new paragraph on its own.

\begin{enumerate}[after =\vspace*{-\partopsep}]
    \item Did you notice the vertical spacing preceding this list?
    \item Two,
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Two and a half;
        \item Almost three.
    \end{enumerate}
    \item Three.
\end{enumerate}
\textbf{There shouldn't be a vertical spacing here.}
This text is appended to the previous list too.

And finally, a list with preceding text only.
\begin{itemize}[after = \vspace*{\partopsep}]
    \item One,
    \item Two,
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Two and a half;
        \item Almost three.
    \end{itemize}
    \item Three.
\end{itemize}


\textbf{There should be a vertical spacing here.}
This is a new paragraph.
It should thus be preceded with parskip.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's indeed more semantically correct!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using lua to get the next line in the source and check its emptiness. Of course, it only works with lualatex. It may need a bit of refining for quasi-empty lines (only spaces ?).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
function manageNextLine(s)
  luatexbase.remove_from_callback("process_input_buffer", "manageNextLine")
  if s == "" then
    return "\\leavevmode\\par"
  else
    return s
  end
end
\end{luacode*}

\parskip=10ex  % to see it better

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{noitemsep,
         topsep=-\parskip,
         partopsep=\parskip,
         after=\luadirect{luatexbase.add_to_callback("process_input_buffer", manageNextLine , "manageNextLine")}
  }



\begin{document}
Para

Para2
\begin{itemize}
\item 1
\item 2
\end{itemize}
%
Continuing the same para.

Para3
\begin{itemize}
\item A.
\item B.
\end{itemize}

Suite with vertical spacing.

\end{document}
```