# How to get list environment to align at text baseline in a \parbox[t][0pt]{…}

Tags: spacing, lists

This is a follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/438483/87678).

I'm trying to insert text that takes up no vertical space but aligns the same as if it was inserted normally.

The solution provided in the linked question works well for me, except if my text to take up no space begins with a list environment. In this case, the `\parbox` aligns at the top of the text, rather than the baseline.

How can I fix this?

## MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\fi
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newdimen\savedparindent
\newdimen\savedparskip
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{%
  \savedparindent\parindent
  \savedparskip\parskip
  \noindent
  \parbox[t][0pt]{\linewidth}{%
    \parindent\savedparindent
    \parskip\savedparskip
    #1}%
  \vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Some text.

\blap{This should not take up any vertical space, but should align at normal
text baseline (aligned like I want).}

\vspace{2cm}

More text.

\blap{%
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item This should not take up any vertical space, but should align at
      normal text baseline (not aligned like I want).
  \end{itemize}}

\vspace{2cm}

Yet more text.

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item This text takes up vertical space and aligns at normal text baseline
    (aligned like I want for comparison).
\end{itemize}

\newpage

Some text.

\vspace{2cm}

More text.

\vspace{2cm}

Yet more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to bad interaction between `\parbox` and the immediate following `itemize`. See, for instance, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6486/164314). Solution: Use `minipage` instead.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newdimen\savedparindent
\newdimen\savedparskip
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{%
  \savedparindent\parindent
  \savedparskip\parskip
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
    \parindent\savedparindent
    \parskip\savedparskip
    #1%
  \end{minipage}%
  \vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
Some text.

\blap{This should not take up any vertical space, but should align at normal
text baseline (aligned like I want).}

\vspace{2cm}

More text.

\blap{%
  \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item This should not take up any vertical space, but should align at
      normal text baseline (not aligned like I want).
  \end{itemize}}

\vspace{2cm}

Yet more text.

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item This text takes up vertical space and aligns at normal text baseline
    (aligned like I want for comparison).
\end{itemize}

\newpage

Some text.

\vspace{2cm}

More text.

\vspace{2cm}

Yet more text.

\end{document}
```

[image: minipage]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I experimented with using `\smash{\vtop{...}}` for `\blap`.  Alas, it still added an extra line before itemize.

After reading [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6486/164314) I found `\@minipagetrue` got rid of the extra space.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\fi
\usepackage{enumitem}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{\par\vskip-\parskip
  \noindent\smash{\vtop{\@minipagetrue
    #1}}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\allowbreak}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\blap{%
This should not take up any vertical space, but should align at normal
text baseline (aligned like I want).}

\vspace{2cm}

More text.

\blap{%
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item This should not take up any vertical space, but should align at
      normal text baseline (not aligned like I want).
\end{itemize}}

\vspace{2cm}

Yet more text.

\begin{itemize}[nosep]
  \item This text takes up vertical space and aligns at normal text baseline
    (aligned like I want for comparison).
\end{itemize}



\newpage

Some text.

\vspace{2cm}

More text.

\vspace{2cm}

Yet more text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I accept the `minipage` option as I'm looking for alignment on text baseline. Your solution actually seems to align at bottom of character descenders, so spacing is close, but not quite right.

Comment: The extra space is very likely to be `\addvspace` mentioned in [this linked post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6486/164314) of my answer.

Comment: @RuixiZhang - That was it.  Setting the minipage flag got rid of the extra space, although `\let\addvspace\@gobble` did not.