# Behaviour differences between article and memoir with X column in tabularx

Tags: spacing, memoir, tabularx

This is another follow up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/447186/87678).

My current `\blap` macro works in `tabularx` X columns with the `article` class. But it behaves slightly differently with the `memoir` class. Specifically, the vertical correction of `\vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` seems not to be needed with `memoir` in this case. (This vertical correction is still needed in other contexts outside of tables in `memoir`, so I can't get rid of it completely.)

`memoir` emulates `tabularx` but using it's method to use the real `tabularx` package does not make a difference. i.e., this doesn't make any difference:

```
\DisemulatePackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
```

## Question

Can anyone suggest a fix?

I'm happy with either a workaround, a patch to `memoir`, or a robust way to test if I'm in an X column cell, so I can conditionally leave out the `\vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}% works as intended with article
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\fi
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newskip\savedparindent
\newskip\savedparskip
\newskip\savedrightskip
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{%
  \savedparindent\parindent
  \savedparskip\parskip
  \savedrightskip\rightskip
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
    \parindent\savedparindent
    \parskip\savedparskip
    \rightskip\savedrightskip
    #1%
  \end{minipage}%
  % The following line is generally needed to line things up
  % but not in X columns in memoir (article is OK)
  \vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  A1 & \blap{B1} \\[1cm]
  A2 & A2 \\[1cm]
\end{tabularx}
\newpage
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  A1 & B1 \\[1cm]
  A2 & A2 \\[1cm]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: memoir has an (old) copy of the `array` package code it doesn't actually include the current array.sty, probably it needs an update to match the 2018 array release.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that makes sense. Sadly, adding `\DisemulatePackage{array}` generates errors :(.

Comment: Hmm, time to make good of my promise to remove array and tabularx from memoir.

Comment: @daleif, is this something that might be released on CTAN in the near future?

Comment: @DavidPurton in the future yes, not sure when.

Comment: @DavidPurton do you want to test the version which just requires array, delarray, dcolumn and tabularx? Then drop me an email at the obvious gmail address.

Comment: @daleif, the latest version of `memoir`? Do you have a development version? Or will it appear in CTAN shortly. (Latest date on CTAN I see is from April)

Comment: @DavidPurton I have an unreleased version. I'll probably look at some other bugs before releasing it, but would be nice to have it tested in advance.

Comment: @daleif, no pros. I'll test it. Just let me know where to get it from.

Comment: As mentioned above send me an email, then I'll email you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comment. Until I get around to actually removing `array` and `tabularx` from `memoir`, this seems to work on TL18.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{memoir}% works as intended with article
\usepackage{ifluatex}
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\fi

\DisemulatePackage{array}
\DisemulatePackage{tabularx}
\let\extratabsurround\relax
\makeatletter
\let\backup@length\relax
\let\firsthline\relax
\let\lasthline\relax
\def\@xhline{\ifx\reserved@a\hline
               \vskip\doublerulesep
               \vskip-\arrayrulewidth
             \fi
      \ifnum0=`{\fi}}
\newcommand\undefcolumntype[1]{\expandafter\let\csname NC@find@#1\endcsname\relax}
\newcommand\forcenewcolumntype[1]{\undefcolumntype{#1}\newcolumntype{#1}}
\undefcolumntype{X}
\undefcolumntype{*}
\makeatother
\usepackage{array,tabularx}

\newskip\savedparindent
\newskip\savedparskip
\newskip\savedrightskip
\newcommand{\blap}[1]{%
  \savedparindent\parindent
  \savedparskip\parskip
  \savedrightskip\rightskip
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}[t][0pt]{\linewidth}
    \parindent\savedparindent
    \parskip\savedparskip
    \rightskip\savedrightskip
    #1%
  \end{minipage}%
  % The following line is generally needed to line things up
  % but not in X columns in memoir (article is OK)
  \vspace*{-\parskip}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  A1 & \blap{B1} \\[1cm]
  A2 & A2 \\[1cm]
\end{tabularx}
\newpage
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  A1 & B1 \\[1cm]
  A2 & A2 \\[1cm]
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I just kept relaxing stuff until it did not complain anymore. The code for removing a defined column type is from here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157062/3929