# Tikzposter and horizontal spacing issues with itemize and descriptive list

Tags: itemize, description, tikzposter, bullets

I start with posting the smallest segment of code I was able to create for reproducing this problem:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames,a0paper, subcolspace = 3 mm, colspace = 3 mm, landscape, innermargin = 0 mm,  margin = 0 mm, blockhorizontalspace = 5 mm, blockverticalspace = 5 mm, 25 pt]{tikzposter} 

\usetheme{Envelope} % See Section 5 (Rätt okej!)
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
    \setlength{\TP@blocktop}{.495\textheight}
\makeatother

\settitle{ }

\begin{columns}
    \column{0.49975}
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{MidnightBlue!100}
    \block[bodyoffsetx = 0 mm, bodyoffsety=-2cm,bodyverticalshift = 0 mm,bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em,roundedcorners=0]{}{\color{white} \fontsize{80pt}{80pt}\selectfont \flushleft \bf{Main question? \\ \fontsize{60pt}{60pt}\selectfont \begin{description}
                                                                                                                                           \item[ $\bullet$] Bullet 1 description
                                                                                                                                           \item[ $\bullet$] Bullet 2 description
    \begin{itemize}
                                                                      \item Bullet 1 itemize
                                                                      \item Bullet 2 itemize
    \colorlet{blockbodybgcolor}{white!60}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

And the resulting figure:

[image: Figure showing problems occuring with bullet lists in blocks using tikzposter]

There you can see that using the "normal" bullet list approach, the bullets will begin before/outside the beginning of the block.

I dound a trick to go around it, with desrciptive list and `\item[ $\bullet$]`. That is however a "cheap solution" and should not have to be like that.

Any suggestions what I did wrong in the first place?

Thanks on advance!

Comment: You are tampering with a lot of 'seps". Have you tried to uncomment those and see which of those drives the change in the list behavior? Also this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-and-parsep-what-does-each-of-them-mean-and-wha) may be helpful to sort those out or as a starting point for a workaround.

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure if I understand what you mean by "seps" here.

Comment: bodyinnersep = 3 mm,titleinnersep = 0em and friends...
I guess the question is, if you start with a blank tikzposter, without invoking all the optional length changes (to the documentclass) and/or the block, do you have the same issue?

Comment: Good question. I'll have to look that up. Lots of quick and dirty tweaking has taken place ...

Comment: Matthias: If one uses `bodyinnersep = 0 mm` the content of a box comes immediately at the border of the box. So it might not be a good idea, as I see it.

Comment: Matthias: The reason I tried to put things like `titleinnersep = 0em` is that I do not like the titles of the boxes included in this packade. I want to design my boxes myself. Maybe it was the wrong way of doint it?

Comment: Matthias: But you were right in that is somehow was related to some of these settings. It works out fine now it seems. After some cleansing.

Comment: Glad you could work it out. Maybe just answer your own question, i.e., provide the cleansed source code, and explain what the problem was, so others may benefit in the future.

Comment: First of all, note that the code in your question is incomplete, and throws errors as it stands. You're missing `\end{itemize} \end{description} }}`. One closing brace is for the `\bf{`, one for the `\block{`. So I don't get any output from your code. Unrelated: `\bf` has been deprecate for 25 years, and it's not a command that takes an argument, but a switch that affects the following text in the same group. That is, you should use `\bfseries` instead, and it's used as `{\bfseries ...}`.