# Spacing between multiple lines of an item in itemize or enumerate

Tags: enumerate, itemize, line-spacing, enumitem

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
Some text here.
\begin{enumerate}
\item a
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Assume item a contains multiple lines of text. How can I increase the spacing between each line in item a ?

Comment: Reset `\parskip` in item a only?

Comment: where should I put `\parskip` ?

Comment: I answered the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `before` key allows to change the `\baselineskip`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
Some text here.
\begin{enumerate}[before=\setlength{\baselineskip}{20pt},itemsep=-10pt]
\item a more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text 
\item b
\item c
\end{enumerate}
Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using the `enumitem` package you can set the parsep and itemsep parameters.  `parsep` controls the amount of space between paragraphs, `itemsep` that between items: see [other page on this site.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/topsep-itemsep-partopsep-and-parsep-what-does-each-of-them-mean-and-wha)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    Some text here.
    \begin{enumerate}[parsep=20pt,itemsep=10pt]
        \item a
        \item b
        \item c
    \end{enumerate}
    Some more text.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This didn't work. It only increases the space between items a and b.

Comment: thought that's what you wanted, ok