# Adding a list inside of a table

Tags: tables, lists

Basically i'm trying to add create this table : [image]

But I'm stuck with the listing inside of a table! Here's my try even though it's nothing like this:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l|l| }
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Résumé de l'identification} \\
\hline
Nom du cas  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Ajouter un nouvelle page} \\ \hline
Objectifs  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Ça consiste  à ajouter une nouvelle page avec un contenu statiques, } \\ \hline
Résumé  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{L'utilisateur doit ajouter un titre et un contenu grâce à un l'outil WYSIWYG\footnote{What You See Is What You Get} } \\ \hline
Acteur  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Utilisateur} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Description d’enchainement} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Préconditions }  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Post-Conditions} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{L'utilisateur a le droit de créer autant de page qui lui est consacré par rapport a son pack}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{La nouvelle page est ajouté à la base de données} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{Scénario Principal} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{ |c| }{
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
      \item L'administrateur  remplit  le formulaire  et cliquez  sur le bouton  Ajouter
      \item Le système  valide  les entrées
\item  Le système  enregistre  le nouvel  utilisateur  dans la base de données
\item Le système   redirige  l'administrateur  à la page de liste  des utilisateurs 
      \end{itemize}
      } \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Any help with this?

Comment: Woud it http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54039/a-list-inside-a-table?rq=1 be helpful?

Comment: another option is to make the column a `p` column, then you can enter normal `\begin{enumerate}...\end{enumerate}` in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution, using `tabularx, threeparttable` for the footnote, `colortbl`, `xcolor` and `enumitem`, and also `frenchb` as I supposed your document will be in French. I modified the label font for small caps (personal taste) and let the cation go to its normal position for tables – on top.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, french]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{fourier}
    \usepackage[sups]{heuristica}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \renewcommand\frenchtablename{Tableau}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

    \usepackage{array, tabularx, threeparttable, caption}
    \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
    \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\hsize=2\hsize}X}
    \newcolumntype{Z}{>{\hsize=3\hsize}X}
    \captionsetup{font =small, labelfont = sc}

    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{colortbl}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \setcounter{table}{1}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
    \arrayrulecolor{DodgerBlue3}\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Description textuelle de cas d’utilisation «~Ajouter un nouvel utilisateur~»}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{4}{X|}}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{CadetBlue1!50}\multicolumn{4}{|l|}{\bfseries Résumé de l'identification} \\
    \hline
    \cellcolor{CadetBlue1!50}Nom du cas & \multicolumn{3}{Z|}{Ajouter un nouvelle page} \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{CadetBlue1!50}Objectifs & \multicolumn{3}{Z|}{Ça consiste à ajouter une nouvelle page avec un contenu statique, } \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{CadetBlue1!50}Résumé & \multicolumn{3}{Z|}{L'utilisateur doit ajouter un titre et un contenu grâce à un outil \mbox{\scshape wysiwyg}\tnote{\textsu{1}}. } \\ \hline
    \cellcolor{CadetBlue1!50}Acteur & \multicolumn{3}{Z|}{Utilisateur} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{CadetBlue1!50}\multicolumn{4}{ |l| }{\bfseries Description d’enchainement} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{CadetBlue1!50}\multicolumn{2}{|Y|}{Préconditions } & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{Post-Conditions} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|Y|}{L'utilisateur a le droit de créer autant de pages qu’il lui est consacré par rapport à son pack} & \multicolumn{2}{Y|}{La nouvelle page est ajoutée à la base de données} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{CadetBlue1!50}\multicolumn{4}{ |l| }{\bfseries Scénario Principal} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|m{0.9\linewidth}| }{%
    \begin{enumerate}[\bfseries 1., itemsep = 0ex, wide = 2em, ]
    \item L'administrateur remplit le formulaire et cliquez sur le bouton Ajouter
    \item Le système valide les entrées
    \item Le système enregistre le nouvel utilisateur dans la base de données
    \item Le système redirige l'administrateur à la page de liste des utilisateurs
    \end{enumerate}
    } \\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \vskip 0.5ex
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[\textsu{1}]\footnotesize What You See Is What You Get.
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but it displays me this error at `\usepackage[sups]{heuristica}` `! LaTeX Error: File `heuristica.sty' not found.l.5     \usepackage {geometry}^^M`

Comment: Comment it: it is a recent complement to `fourier`, to have true small caps, superior figures, &c. It's only in the latest TeXLive (2014), and since February, I think, in MiKTeX. In that case, remove the two `\texsu{1}` commands just by `1` – they are superiors figures for footnotes.

Comment: Still it doesn't display ! Could you please try it here  ? https://www.writelatex.com/1212232fygqzq#/2916852/

Comment: I tried, but do I do to compile? I  never used writelatex.

Comment: It compile as you write the code at the preview area or you can change it to manual and hit `refresh preview` once you've finished

Comment: Now it works: there also was another culprit: `renewcommand\frenchtablename{…}`, which uses the new syntax of `frenchb`(v. 3.0). Apparently, they have the previous version.

Answer (score 3):

The `fancybox` package has the `Benumerate` enviroment that will work just fine.

```
\begin{Benumerate}
      \item L'administrateur  remplit  le formulaire  et cliquez  sur le bouton  Ajouter
      \item Le système  valide  les entrées
\item  Le système  enregistre  le nouvel  utilisateur  dans la base de données
\item Le système   redirige  l'administrateur  à la page de liste  des utilisateurs 
      \end{Benumerate}
```

There are also others enviroments. See [here](http://doc.ctrlaltdel.ch/LaTeX/fancybox/fancybox.pdf) for more details (pages 12 and 13)

Comment: Sorry but still !`Environment Benumearte undefined` even when I've added it's package

Comment: There's a typo: It's Benumerate and not Benumearte

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways of solving your problem.

1. Using a `minipage` environment.
2. Using a `p` type column.

Here are the solutions. I am presenting only the parts of interest since the other portions are not relevant to the problem.

---

```
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
        \item L'administrateur remplit le formulaire et cliquez sur le
          bouton Ajouter
        \item Le système valide les entrées
        \item Le système enregistre le nouvel utilisateur dans la base
          de données
        \item Le système redirige l'administrateur à la page de liste
          des utilisateurs
        \end{itemize}
      \end{minipage}}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{4}{|p{0.8\textwidth}|}{
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt]
        \item L'administrateur remplit le formulaire et cliquez sur le
          bouton Ajouter
        \item Le système valide les entrées
        \item Le système enregistre le nouvel utilisateur dans la base
          de données
        \item Le système redirige l'administrateur à la page de liste
          des utilisateurs
        \end{itemize}}\\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```