# How to generate a table with items into a box?

Tags: lists, longtable

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}<br/>
\usepackage{ltablex,array,ragged2e}
\let\FNS\footnotesize

\begin{document}
{\tabcolsep=2pt\small\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
  l 
  >{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}p{0.15\linewidth}% \hspace to allow hyphenation of first word
  *2{>{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}X}
  >{\hspace{0pt}\RaggedRight}p{0.15\linewidth}
  @{}}
\caption{CLASIFICACIÓN DE LOS MEDICAMENTOS DE ACUERDO A LAS PRINCIPALES ACCIONES FARMACOLÓGICAS Y/O USOS TERAPEÚTICOS}\\


 GRUPO No. & DESCRIPCIÓN&MEDICAMENTOS\\
  1 &Drogas que actuán en la sinápsis y uniones deuroefectoras& Agonistas colinérgicos\\
                                                                Agentes colinesterasa\\
                                                                Atropina\\
                                                                Escopolamina\\
                                                                Drogas simpaticomiméticas\\ \hline                                                              
  2 & Drogas que actúan sobre el sistema nerviosos central&     Anestésicos
                                                                Gases terapéuticos
                                                                Hipnóticos
                                                                Sedantes
                                                                Antiepilépticos
                                                                Opioides
                                                                Analgésicos\\ \hline
    3 & Antinflamatorios & Histaminas& Derivados lipídicos
                                     Tratamiento antiasma
                                     Analgésicos antipiréticos\\ \hline
  4 &lones y sales& Sales de sodio
                    Sales de potasio\\ \hline
  5 & Drogas que afectan el sistema renal y el metabolismo de electrólitos& Xantinas
                                                                            Diuréticos osmóticos
                                                                            Compuestos mercuriales
                                                                            Tiacidas y sulfonamidas
                                                                            Inhibidores de la anhidrasa carbónica \\ \hline
  6 & Agentes cardiovasculares & Nitratos orgánicos
                                 Antihipertensivos
                                 Glucósidos cardiacos
                                 Antirrítmicos          \\ \hline

  7 & Fármacos que afectan funciones intestinales& Control de la acidez
                                                   Control de úlceras
                                                   Motilidad gastrointestinal
                                                   Producción de ácidos biliares y jugos digestivos
          \\ \hline

\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

I would like to generate this table but I'm new with latex and I would love some help

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SX. Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54039/a-list-inside-a-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possibility to do so. This table fits exactly on a page of an 11pt-book. If you need to do a page break, please read the documentation of the `longtable` package. You can reduce some more white space when having a look on Bernard's comment below. A `makecell` would reduce the width of the first column.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{CLASIFICACIÓN DE LOS MEDICAMENTOS DE ACUERDO A LAS PRINCIPALES ACCIONES FARMACOLÓGICAS Y/O USOS TERAPEÚTICOS}  
        \begin{tabular}{cp{3cm}p{6.4cm}}\toprule            
            \MakeUppercase{Grupo} No. & \MakeUppercase{Descripción} & \MakeUppercase{Medicamentos}\\\midrule
            1 & Drogas que actuán en la sinápsis y uniones deuroefectoras & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Agonistas colinérgicos
            \item Agentes colinesterasa
            \item Atropina
            \item Escopolamina
            \item Drogas simpaticomiméticas
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace                                                              
            2 & Drogas que actúan sobre el sistema nerviosos central & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Anestésicos
            \item Gases terapéuticos
            \item Hipnóticos
            \item Sedantes
            \item Antiepilépticos
            \item Opioides
            \item Analgésicos
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            3 & Antiinflamatorios & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Histaminas
            \item Derivados lipídicos
            \item Tratamiento antiasma
            \item Analgésicos antipiréticos
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            4 & Iones y sales& \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Sales de sodio
            \item Sales de potasio
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            5 & Drogas que afectan el sistema renal y el metabolismo de electrólitos & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Xantinas
            \item Diuréticos osmóticos
            \item Compuestos mercuriales
            \item Tiacidas y sulfonamidas
            \item Inhibidores de la anhidrasa carbónica 
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            6 & Agentes cardiovasculares & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Nitratos orgánicos
            \item Antihipertensivos
            \item Glucósidos cardiacos
            \item Antirrítmicos          
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace           
            7 & Fármacos que afectan funciones intestinales & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Control de la acidez
            \item Control de úlceras
            \item Motilidad gastrointestinal
            \item Producción de ácidos biliares y jugos digestivos
            \end{itemize*}\\\bottomrule         
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Update**:

As requested, here is a `longtable`-version of your table.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption} % for nicer spacing below the captions. Please see the [short version] in the first caption and adapt it
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lmodern} % scalable version of your font
\usepackage{microtype} % for better kerning (nicer distribution of the words in narrow columns)
\usepackage{longtable} % splitable tables. Do not put those in a float.
\usepackage{makecell} % for the \makecell in the first row
%\usepackage{showframe} switch this on for manual adjustment of the p-columns

\begin{document}  
        \begin{longtable}{cp{3.5cm}p{6.5cm}}
            \caption[Short version for the LoF!!!]{CLASIFICACIÓN DE LOS MEDICAMENTOS DE ACUERDO A LAS PRINCIPALES ACCIONES FARMACOLÓGICAS Y/O USOS TERAPEÚTICOS}\\
            \toprule            
            \makecell{\MakeUppercase{Grupo}\\No.} & \MakeUppercase{Descripción} & \MakeUppercase{Medicamentos}\\\midrule
            \endfirsthead
            \caption[]{(continued)}\\
            \toprule            
            \makecell{\MakeUppercase{Grupo}\\No.} & \MakeUppercase{Descripción} & \MakeUppercase{Medicamentos}\\\midrule
            \endhead
            \bottomrule
            \endfoot
            1 & Drogas que actuán en la sinápsis y uniones deuroefectoras & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Agonistas colinérgicos
            \item Agentes colinesterasa
            \item Atropina
            \item Escopolamina
            \item Drogas simpaticomiméticas
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace                                                              
            2 & Drogas que actúan sobre el sistema nerviosos central & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Anestésicos
            \item Gases terapéuticos
            \item Hipnóticos
            \item Sedantes
            \item Antiepilépticos
            \item Opioides
            \item Analgésicos
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            3 & Antiinflamatorios & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Histaminas
            \item Derivados lipídicos
            \item Tratamiento antiasma
            \item Analgésicos antipiréticos
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            4 & Iones y sales& \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Sales de sodio
            \item Sales de potasio
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            5 & Drogas que afectan el sistema renal y el metabolismo de electrólitos & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Xantinas
            \item Diuréticos osmóticos
            \item Compuestos mercuriales
            \item Tiacidas y sulfonamidas
            \item Inhibidores de la anhidrasa carbónica 
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            6 & Agentes cardiovasculares & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Nitratos orgánicos
            \item Antihipertensivos
            \item Glucósidos cardiacos
            \item Antirrítmicos          
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            7 & Drogas que afectan el sistema renal y el metabolismo de electrólitos &
            \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Xantinas
            \item Diuréticos osmóticos
            \item Compuestos mercuriales
            \item Tiacidas y sulfonamidas
            \item Inhibidores de la anhidrasa carbónica 
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace
            8 & Agentes cardiovasculares & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Nitratos orgánicos
            \item Antihipertensivos
            \item Glucósidos cardiacos
            \item Antirrítmicos          
            \end{itemize*}\\
            \addlinespace           
            9 & Fármacos que afectan funciones intestinales & \begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\newline}]
            \item Control de la acidez
            \item Control de úlceras
            \item Motilidad gastrointestinal
            \item Producción de ácidos biliares y jugos digestivos
            \end{itemize*}\\         
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very ingenious use of the `itemize*` environment! In the first column, you should use the  `makecell` package, in order allow writing `\makecell{GRUPO\\ No.}`, thus getting a less wide column.

Comment: I'm so glad there are people like you @LaRiFaRi. Well, I found this page online, and I still don't know how to use it well, that's why the las thing I wrote "was a big pile of unformated code" U.U, but well I was trying to generate this table, but actually it is twice big as the one u did me the favor to solve and well I still don't know how to use the longtables. :(
P.D Forgive my bad english too :D

Comment: Please see my edit. You will have to look at the captions, if they do what you want. Glad I could help.