# Can't make list in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, itemize

I am a bit new to LaTeX so I am not sure what the workaround is for not being able to use itemize within a tabular environment. Is there a better package for this, perhaps? Can you just not embed environments? Even if it were possible, I am not sure how it would look, considering the tabular format seems to be along the lines of:

item1 & item2\\

item3 & item4\\

Any tips for doing that kind of LaTeX magic?

Comment: Hi, welcome. Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54045/ answer your question?

Comment: you have not shown any relevant code, but I would guess you are using a l c or r column that are always one-line so can not have a list use a `p{3cm}` column for a column that can take vertical material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer)

You appear under the impression that it's not possible to have an `itemize` environment (or some other list-like environment) inside a `tabular` environment. *This impression is incorrect.* This claim may be verified easily by compiling the following minimalist code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{5cm}|}
  \hline
  \begin{itemize}
    \item bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla
  \end{itemize}\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{document}
```

The key to success is to house list-like environments such as `enumerate` and `itemize` in a `p`-type column. As @DavidCarlisle has pointed out in a comment, the `l`, `c`, and `r` column types won't do.

Two additional comments:

- If the document loads the `array` package, the `m` and `b` column types are ok as well. Of course, the `m` and `b` (short for "middle" and "bottom" alignment, I suppose) column types are very close relatives of the `p` column type.
- The `tabularx` and `tabulary` packages define additional column types -- `X`; and `L`, `C`, `R` and `J`, respectively -- which are also capable of housing list-like environments. These new column types are also based on the basic-LaTeX `p` column type.